# jqscroll/jqscrollTo not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

This references the http://jsfiddle.net/PDtRA/ the shows the scroll div inside the menu div.  Is there a way to have the target outside of the #menu? 
i have a sticky header, with fixed position at the top. I am trying to get the target div to scroll under the sticky header.  i am using the same Ariel Flesler scroll js as  the fiddle... but my scroll will not.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.localscroll-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    // When the document is loaded...
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
    // Scroll the content inside the #scroll-container div
        //alert($('#menu').length);
        $('#menu').localScroll({
        target:'#hom'
        });   
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#inter">INTERACTIVE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#time"> TIME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#vis">VIS-COMM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dig">DIGI-PAINT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="hom">
    <div id="inter"> some stuff</div>
    <div id="time"> some stuff</div>
    <div id="vis"> some stuff</div>
    <div id="dig"> some stuff</div>
</div>
```

url: http://www.pensyl.com/p51StudentH.html

Answer (score 0):

Set style of overflow scroll on div with id = hom

```
<div id="hom" style="overflow:scroll;">
    <div id="inter"> some stuff</div>
    <div id="time"> some stuff</div>
    <div id="vis"> some stuff</div>
    <div id="dig"> some stuff</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.